# Calculated properties in Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-data

Consider an Core Data entity with two properties: `text` and -for the sake of simplicity- `textLength`. `textLength` is a property that is calculated every time `text` changes. I have three requirements:

1. Update `textLength` every time `text` changes, ideally inside the `NSManagedObject` subclass.
2. `textLength` cannot be calculated on demand for performance reasons (the actual calculated property that I'm using is much more expensive to calculate).
3. Update the UI every time `text` changes.

My solution is almost there. I'm providing a custom accessor for `setText:`, like this:

```
- (void)setText:(NSString *)text
{
    static NSString *key;
    if (!key) key = NSStringFromSelector(@selector(text));
    [self willChangeValueForKey:key];
    [self setPrimitiveText:text];
    self.textCount = text.count;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:key];
}
```

And using KVO in the UI to observer text changes:

```
[someObject addObserver:self forKeyPath:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(text)) options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:someContext];
```

This works fine in most cases, except when I perform undo. I take that Core Data calls `setPrimiteValue:forKey:` directly, and this does not trigger my calculation logic. As a consequence, when the UI is notified of the change, the `textLength` value is outdated.

Short of calculating `textLength` on demand, where should the calculation logic be?

Answer (score 1):

This is the purpose of the `- (void)awakeFromSnapshotEvents:(NSSnapshotEventType)flags` method. It tells you the reason for the snap shot change and allows you to update computed / derived data.

(when you update the derived value you should set it using the appropriate primitive method)

Comment: +1 Nice! So you would recommend putting the calculation logic in both places (the custom accessor, and `awakeFromSnapshotEvents:`)?

Comment: I just tried this and it appears `awakeFromSnapshotEvents:` is called after the KVO notification is fired, so it doesn't solve the problem either. Well, I guess I could observe `textLength` as well, but it would be nice to keep it simpler.

Comment: Actually no. I still have a problem because the UI is being notified of a change when the object is in an inconsistent state, and this could cause bugs.

Comment: Why aren't you observing the text count? It is always changed last and notifications are sent synchronously.

Comment: @Wain- This will cause crash.. bcoz  object is in an inconsistent state when notification is called.

Comment: Just to check, did you call `super` in `awakeFromSnapshotEvents:`? You must, and you must call it first before any of your custom code.

Comment: @Wain I get notified for the `text` change and for the `textLength` change. During the first notification the object is in an inconsistent state. Yes, I'm calling super in `awakeFromSnapshotEvents:`.

Comment: As @Wain said, just listen for the text count change and update both places because you know if the count changed then the text changed.